# Polynomials and divided differences

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, finite-differences

I would greatly appreciate any hint for proving the following.

Question: Let $f:[0, 1] \to {\bf R}$. Can it be proved that if $[0, 1/(N+m),\dots, (N+m)/(N+m) ; f ]=0$ for all $m=1,2, 3,\dots$, then $f$ is necessarily a polynomial of degree less than or equal to $N$?

(Here $[0, 1/(N+m),\dots, (N+m)/(N+m) ; f]$ denotes the divided difference of $f$ on the nodes $0, 1/(N+m), \dots, 1$.)

Remark: In order to make it easier to obtain a proof, it can be supposed that $f$ satisfies some smoothness properties, as for example to be infinitely differentiable or analytic on $[0, 1]$.

Thank you,

G

Comment: In your question, it is not clear to me whether or not continuity of $f$ on $[0,1]$ is a requirement ... is it? Otherwise $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ given by,
$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} 0 &;x\in\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1] \newline 1 &;x\in[0,1]\backslash \mathbb{Q} \end{cases}$$
may be relevant.

Comment: Thank you for your remark, in the question of course that  f must be supposed at least continuous on [0, 1], but as I said in the Remark, it could be supposed to be differentiable too, if that hypothesis would be helpful for the proof.

Irene

Comment: Cheers for confirming.

Comment: I don't know enough about the background of this question to determine whether it is "off-topic" -- but I ask people who vote to close on such or similar grounds to make sure they *do* know. 

Comment: Actually this is the point of the question, that in the class of all continuous functions on [0, 1], only the polynomials of degree < or = N satisfy that condition. 

Intuitively, this is suggested by the fact that the set of knots 1/(N+m), ..., (N+m)/(N+m), when m takes all the natural numbers, is dense in [0, 1].